# Operation not permitted using createTempFile on 2 file android

Tags: android, file, kotlin

got "Operation not permitted" when try to crate second file on android sdk 24.
in the first one have no problem. all ready have permission in the manifest

code:

```
 fun createVideoFileName(): File? {
        val name = "VIDEO"
        val videoFile = File.createTempFile(name , ".mp4", VideoFolder)
        val audioFile = File.createTempFile(name , ".mp3", VideoFolder)
        AudioFileName = audioFile.absolutePath
        return videoFile.absolutePath
    }
```

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

if i delete "VideoFolder" in the second line it work and create it to tmp dir
if i crate only first file it's work.
if i using another dir it don't work

directory are exists

error:

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
> W/System.err:     at
> java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
> W/System.err:     at
> java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
> W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2018)
> W/System.er

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am having the same issue. Thanks